# AEM : Property Index

Tags: indexing, lucene, aem, jackrabbit-oak

I am working in Property Index in AEM, I am very curious to know which algorithm and data structure is used to create and store these indexes. However, I found various documents specifying how does property index are created but could not find any details about how do they work internally.